# Meteor HTTP Package, Make Request to NTLM Auth API

Tags: authentication, soap, meteor, ntlm

I'm early on in the meteor.js game, and I'm trying to make a SOAP request to a server that requires NTLM authentication. I'm currently using the HTTP package and structuring my request in the format:

```
HTTP.get(url, { content: SOAPenvelope, auth: username+":"+password }
```

However, this is not working due to the authentication; I believe the auth param is meant for HTTP Basic Auth, not NTLM. Does anyone know how I could get this to work with NTLM Auth (or if there is a different package better suited to this?)? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ruben I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Meteor's core HTTP package unfortunately does not support such advanced options and encourage package authors to implement such features that are not scoped within a basic usecase subset.

Therefore some community members have stepped up to create replacement packages such as https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/http-more and https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/http

Although neither these two exactly provide NTLM authentication out box, you can check their sources for inspiration, and perhaps contribute back what you've built upon

Comment: PS: I know this is not exactly the answer you are looking for, but in case you don't get one, I hope this can give you some headway.